# Group by with related_name relation using Prefetch

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I need to make an API with this body structure for graph with multiple lines:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Test title",
    "dots": [
      {
        "date": "2023-03-03",
        "sum_weight": 5000
      },
      {
        "date": "2023-03-06",
        "sum_weight": 1500
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I have a problem with Prefetch, since it's not possible to use .values() to do group_by `date` during query. Right now my ungrouped API looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Test title",
    "dots": [
      {
        "date": "2023-03-03",
        "sum_weight": 5000
      },
      {
        "date": "2023-03-06",
        "sum_weight": 500
      }, 
      {
        "date": "2023-03-06",
        "sum_weight": 1000
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My code right now:

Query:

```
groups = Group.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch("facts",
             queryset=Facts.objects.order_by("date").annotate(sum_weight=Sum("weight")))
)
```

Serializers:

```
class GraphDot(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sum_weight = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_sum_weight(self, obj):
        if not hasattr(obj, 'sum_weight'):
            return 0
        return obj.sum_weight

    class Meta:
        model = Facts
        fields = read_only_fields = ("date", "sum_weight",)


class FoodGraphSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dots = GraphDot(many=True, source="facts")

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = read_only_fields = ("title", "dots")
```

**Is there any way to make a query that is grouped by `date` so my `sum_weight` annotation is summed within it?**

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work and have no way to check it, but wouldn't Window functions work? Window(expression=Sum('weight'),partition_by=[F('date')],order_by='date')

Comment: so whole Prefetch would like like that: Prefetch("facts", queryset=Facts.objects.annotate(sum_weight=Window(expression=Sum('weight'),partition_by=[F('date')],order_by='date')))

Comment: @PTomasz You are the GOAT. Your query didn't do the trick, but after reserching Window expression, I've modified your suggested code a bit and it WORKED! I'll post result as answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @PTomasz comment, I've added Window expression to my query.

So the final query looks like this:

```
groups = Group.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch("facts",
             queryset=Facts.objects.annotate(
                 sum_weight=Window(
                     expression=Sum('weight'), 
                     partition_by=[F('date')],
                     order_by=OrderBy(F('date'))))
             .distinct("date"))
)
```

Without `.distinct("date")` objects were still duplicating, but with right `sum_weight` (both had 1500).

With it everyting is good.

Comment: Would it work with `order_by=F('date')` or `order_by=OrderBy(F('date'))` is required?

Comment: I've tried, but it raises `\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\expressions.py", line 1300, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: order_by must be either an Expression or a sequence of expressions.`

Comment: What Django version are you using? 4.0.X?

Comment: It's an old project, so ==3.2.